# Duplicate entire row values google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, split

I have a problem that I was hoping you guys could help me with!!

I have a table on google sheets that looks something like this:

| ColA | ColB | ColC |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Title 1 | Date 1 | **John,Mark** |
| Title 2 | Date 2 | Susan |
| Title 3 | Date 3 | John |

I was wondering if there is a way that could split names on ColC joined by a "comma" into a new row copying all other values, like:

| ColA | ColB | ColC |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Title 1 | Date 1 | John |
| **Title 1** | **Date 1** | **Mark** |
| Title 2 | Date 2 | Susan |
| Title 3 | Date 3 | John |

Thanks for the help in advance!!!

Answer (score 1):

You may try:

```
=query(index(split(tocol(A2:A&"|"&B2:B&"|"&split(C2:C,",")),"|")),"where Col3!='' format Col2 'd-mmm-yyy'")
```

[image]

Comment: hi @rockinfreakshow

its not quite working with the setup I have, let me give you some more details, sorry

my table has 24 columns, from A-X, the data I need to split, like ColC, is on the "V" column, Col22, for some reason, once I hit like column20, it throws an error saying that the column doesnt exist. I tried to move that column to the fist positions but then the result gets all weird, and one more thing, on that same column I can have blank cells and those are being excluded

Comment: it would help if you could share a sample sheet with demo data and expected output(manually entered) so as for us to work it out directly.

Comment: here is a sample sheet....I've highlighted the rows on the "originalData" tab that should be duplicated based on column V, and on the "expectedResults" I also highlighted the rows  I hope this helps!
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cHT-mC8-wMmgGSrnerz86SOFmjI4g1MjuvnfKr-n_hw/edit#gid=909068591

Comment: Updated the formula in `Cell AA1` of your `expectedResults` tab. Please do check it out.